# What does VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL mean when declaring variables on stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I found this when I tried to learn my friend's query in creating stored procedure. I wonder what does `varchar(max) = null` when declaring the variables?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_EmployeeBasicData]
    @EmployerCode VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @LocationCode VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @UserId VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @Module VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT DISTINCT
        a.EmployerCode,
```

Comment: If you look at the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you will see its assigning a default.

Comment: Please, always read any official documentation before asking a question here.

Comment: I wonder if your friend *really* needs 2GB of space to store things like a user's ID, or an error code... Are their user's IDs really 2 Billion~ characters long? If so, those poor users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a default value for a parameter when the value for that parameter is not explicitly specified in the EXEC statement. NULL does nothing special (in this context), it could be whatever other appropriate value.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyGreatSP
@Param1 int,
@Param2 varchar(50) = 'AAAA'
AS
SELECT @Param1, @Param2;
GO

EXEC MyGreatSP @Param1 = 1
go
--- 1, AAAA
EXEC MyGreatSP @Param1 = 1, @Param2 = 'BBBBB'
go
--- 1, BBBBB
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/specify-parameters